# Moxios: How to access requests that aren't the most recent in unit tests

Tags: axios, moxios

A have a page that on render sends out multiple HTTP get requests for data. How do I filter through `moxios.requests` to get the request with a certain URL to respond to?

The only method I can find online is `moxios.requests.mostRecent()`, however I'm not certain what the most recent request would be. Even then, is there a another method to pop another request?

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this on the moxios library here: https://github.com/axios/moxios

```
 let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent() // How to get 'some/url/' here? This expect is currently failing
      expect(request.url).to.equal('some/url/')
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: []
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access requests by index like so: `moxios.requests.at(0)` for the first request, `moxios.requests.at(1)` for the next one and so on.
I found that out here:
https://github.com/axios/moxios/issues/10